# How to fix simpleXML “Warning: Illegal string offset” for node name?

Tags: php, simplexml

I work with simpleXML to parse some XML responses from server, which I load like this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
```

It has a one and only one child, but with different names for different responses, so I get child name first:

```
$node = $xml->children()->getName();
```

I make new object Response and set his properties to what I read from that XML string:

```
return (new Response())
    ->setTime((string)$xml['time'])
    ->setId((string)$xml->$node['id'])
    ->setResult((string)$xml->$node['result'])
    ->setBalance((string)$xml->$node->balance['value']);
```

And here this warning comes - `Illegal string offset 'id'`, `Illegal string offset 'result'`

I know, that `$node` is actually a string, but it used as name of the node in response.
If I change my code to `->setId((string)$xml->result['id'])`, the warning disappear.
The problem, that I do not know the name of the node, before response actually comes
(for example it can be "good_result", "result_1" and so on).
So, the '$node['id']' is not ask for string index, but for attribute of node.
It looks like collision between PHP string index syntax and simpleXML node name syntax.

1. The code itself work just fine, warning comes only in IDE
2. There are a lot of similar questions about simpleXML, but no answer to my case
3. I need just to remove that warning, so answer how to fix it in code, or remove such warnings are accepted

Comment: It's most likely because your IDE interprets `$xml->$node['id']` as "get property `$node['id']` of `$xml`" instead of  "get array key `id` of `$xml->$node`". Which IDE are you using? Whichever it is, check what syntax package is loaded for PHP. This warning would have been generated for older versions of PHP, see here: https://3v4l.org/BsOgM

Comment: It is not related to the IDE. What is probably happening here is that your IDE show you warnings, which may not show on the page depending on your error reporting level. If you are happy to just suppress warnings, have a look at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php - you can try calling `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_WARNING);` but it is not recommended.

Comment: @PauloAmaral No, it really is just the IDE, unless the code is running on a truly ancient version of PHP. As El_Vanja points out, the interpretation of that code changed in 7.0. Most likely, the IDE is assuming the old interpretation, and predicting a warning that won't be there in the real code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible ways to interpret code of this form:

```php
$object->$foo['bar'];
```

- Versions of PHP since 7.0 will look up the property identified by `$foo`, and then look up the key `'bar'` on the result, which is what you want.
- Older versions of PHP would evaluate `$foo['bar']` first, and then look up the property based on that result.

The warning in your IDE is assuming the old interpretation: it's warning you that `$foo['bar']` doesn't make sense, because `$foo` is a string.

Unless you're actually running your code in an ancient version of PHP (5.6 [hasn't had an official security update for over 2 years](https://www.php.net/eol.php)), there is no actual problem with the code. You need to either upgrade your IDE, or re-configure it, so that it interprets code the same way the actual PHP will. Since you don't mention what IDE you're using, I can't be more specific.